# Creating an multidimensional array from ES6 generator

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix, ecmascript-6, generator

Here is a generator creating a normal array. What is the quickest way of creating a multi dimensional array?

```
let seq = [...makeSequence(100)];

* makeSequence(max) {
   for (let i = 0; i < max; i++) {
     yield i;
   }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean with *multidimensional*?

Comment: just a simple matrix.

Comment: So actually *twodimensional*...

Comment: indeed. eg. [[2, 1], [4, 3]]

Comment: And what do you expect to be iterated? The outer array? What would an individual yield return? An array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the iterator should return the top-level elements (which would be arrays themselves), then you could use recursion and so support any depth of array nesting:

```js
function * makeSequence(max, dimensionCount = 1) {
   for (let i = 0; i < max; i++) {
     yield dimensionCount <= 1 ? i : [...makeSequence(max, dimensionCount-1)];
   }
}

let seq = [...makeSequence(5, 2)];

console.log(seq);
```